# Submitting to slurm a python script which calls srun

Tags: python, slurm, hpc

I want to submit a python script with slurm, going through bash "sbatch myscript.sh". In my script.sh python is called "python running.py"

Which in turn will use "check_call" from the subroutine module to finally call srun to run a massively-parallelized software.

I would like to know if this will hurt performance somehow, my worry is that python will take one process since it is the job being submitted?

If a slurm/HPC guru could answer my question I would be grateful!

Comment: Curiously, why do you need Python? Why not have bash shell script run the *massively-parallelized software*? Slurm can run any executable.

Comment: I am using Python to run automated workflow, can't change it

Comment: Understood. You don't need to entirely replace Python but the one step that calls the software. Pull it out to bash level and have Python handle inputs and outputs. Curious to see `sh` and `py` specifics and avoid generalities.

Comment: I can't do that, I am using a complex workflow package that does all that. But I got my answer: no, it should not reduce performance. I will let the question open for some times if someone has anything else to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the workflow correctly:

Sbatch -> Bash Script -> Python Script -> Srun -> HPC Workload

If this is the case, and without having more information then i would say youd be introducing a very small (negligible) overhead when submitting the job. But in terms of performance of the entire Workload, if this only happens once at startup, the runtime performance wont be affected.

Comment: That's indeed what I have been told by other users, thanks!~